# TreeLayout not considering node’s location

Tags: javascript, gojs

I use GOJS ER Diagram sample with Layout as TreeLayout. I have set node's location data and IsInitial as false and isOngoing as false and diagram is not positioning based on node's location set. Here my code:

```
dgmEntityRelationship = $(go.Diagram, "dgmEntityRelationship",
        {
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Top,
            allowDelete: false,
            allowCopy: false,
            layout: $(go.TreeLayout,  // use a TreeLayout to position all of the nodes
              {
                  isInitial: false,
                  isOngoing: false,
                  treeStyle: go.TreeLayout.StyleRootOnly,
                  angle: 90,
                  layerSpacing: 80,
                  alternateAngle: 0,
                  alternateAlignment: go.TreeLayout.AlignmentStart,
                  alternateNodeIndent: 20,
                  alternateNodeIndentPastParent: 1,
                  alternateNodeSpacing: 20,
                  alternateLayerSpacing: 40,
                  alternateLayerSpacingParentOverlap: 1,
                  alternatePortSpot: new go.Spot(0, 0.999, 20, 0),
                  alternateChildPortSpot: go.Spot.Left
              }),
            "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
            click: function(e, obj)
            {
                var node = dgmEntityRelationship.selection.first();

                if (node == null)
                {
                    jQuery("#btnShowAddElementModal").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }
        });

    // define several shared Brushes
    var bluegrad = $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(150, 150, 250)", 0.5: "rgb(86, 86, 186)", 1: "rgb(86, 86, 186)" });
    var greengrad = $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(158, 209, 159)", 1: "rgb(67, 101, 56)" });
    var redgrad = $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(206, 106, 100)", 1: "rgb(180, 56, 50)" });
    var yellowgrad = $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 221, 50)", 1: "rgb(254, 182, 50)" });
    var lightgrad = $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 1: "#e1fdfb", 0: "#cfebfe" });

    // the template for each attribute in a node's array of item data
    var itemTempl =
      $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
        $(go.Shape,
          { desiredSize: new go.Size(10, 10) },
          new go.Binding("figure", "figure"),
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")),


        $(go.Panel, "Table",
          {
              margin: 2
          },
        $(go.RowColumnDefinition, { row: 0, sizing: go.RowColumnDefinition.None }),
        $(go.RowColumnDefinition, { column: 0, width: 150 }),
        $(go.RowColumnDefinition, { column: 1, width: 100 }),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          {
              row: 0,
              column: 0, alignment: go.Spot.Left,
              margin: new go.Margin(0, 4, 0, 2),  // leave room for Button
              stroke: "#333333",
              font: "bold 14px Roboto"
          },
          new go.Binding("text", "name")),
           {
               toolTip:  // define a tooltip for each node that displays the color as text
                 $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
                   $(go.Shape, { fill: "#FFFFCC" }),
                   $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 4 },
                     new go.Binding("text", "name"))
                 )  // end of Adornment
           },
        $(go.TextBlock,
          {
              row: 0,
              column: 1,
              alignment: go.Spot.Left,
              margin: new go.Margin(0, 4, 0, 2),  // leave room for Button
              stroke: "#333333",
              font: "bold 14px Roboto"
          },
          new go.Binding("text", "dataType")))
      );

    // define the Node template, representing an entity
    dgmEntityRelationship.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",  // the whole node panel
        {
            selectionAdorned: false,
            resizable: true,
            layoutConditions: go.Part.LayoutStandard & ~go.Part.LayoutNodeSized,
            fromSpot: go.Spot.AllSides,
            toSpot: go.Spot.AllSides,
            isShadowed: true,
            shadowColor: "#d7d7d7",
        },
        {
            click: function (e, obj) {
                var node = dgmEntityRelationship.selection.first();

                if (node != null) {

                    if (node.data.key == "Root") {
                        jQuery("#btnDeleteElement").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    }
                    else {
                        jQuery("#btnDeleteElement").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }

                    jQuery("#btnShowAddElementModal").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }
        },
        new go.Binding("location", "loc").makeTwoWay(),
        // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the Table
        $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
          {
              fill: lightgrad, stroke: "#2196f3", strokeWidth: 1,

          }),
        $(go.Panel, "Table",
          {
              margin: 8, stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill
          },
          $(go.RowColumnDefinition, { row: 0, sizing: go.RowColumnDefinition.None }),
          // the table header
          $(go.TextBlock,
            {
                row: 0, alignment: go.Spot.Center,
                margin: new go.Margin(0, 14, 0, 2),  // leave room for Button
                font: "bold 16px Roboto"
            },
            new go.Binding("text", "key")),
          // the collapse/expand button
          $("PanelExpanderButton", "LIST",  // the name of the element whose visibility this button toggles
            { row: 0, alignment: go.Spot.TopRight }),
          // the list of Panels, each showing an attribute
          $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
            {
                name: "LIST",
                row: 1,
                padding: 3,
                alignment: go.Spot.TopLeft,
                defaultAlignment: go.Spot.Left,
                stretch: go.GraphObject.Horizontal,
                itemTemplate: itemTempl
            },
            new go.Binding("itemArray", "items"))
        )  // end Table Panel
      );  // end Node

    // define the Link template, representing a relationship
    dgmEntityRelationship.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        {
            selectionAdorned: true,
            layerName: "Foreground",
            reshapable: true,
            routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
            corner: 5,
            curve: go.Link.JumpOver
        },
        $(go.Shape,  // the link shape
          { stroke: "#333333", strokeWidth: 1.5}),
        $(go.TextBlock,  // the "from" label
          {
              textAlign: "center",
              font: "14px Roboto",
              stroke: "#1967B3",
              segmentIndex: 0,
              segmentOffset: new go.Point(NaN, NaN),
              segmentOrientation: go.Link.None
          },
          new go.Binding("text", "text")),
        $(go.TextBlock,  // the "to" label
          {
              textAlign: "center",
              font: "bold 14px Roboto",
              stroke: "#1967B3",
              segmentIndex: -1,
              segmentOffset: new go.Point(NaN, NaN),
              segmentOrientation: go.Link.None
          },
          new go.Binding("text", "toText"))
      );

    loadDiagramData();
}
```

Please help me to find the issue. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Some more details would be nice, what have you discovered about the code so far?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no error or warning when using GOJS debug version.  I want the diagram with Treelayout and able to position the nodes wherever I want. I am giving the data.loc as Point values. But still not positioning based on the location set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a TwoWay **Binding** on **Node.location**, which is good.  And you have disabled automatic layout invalidation (**Layout.isInitial** and **Layout.isOngoing**) so that the **Diagram.layout** doesn't automatically move the nodes.

Are there any errors or warnings when using the debug version of the GoJS library?

My guess is that you are not providing instances of **Point** as the values of `data.loc`, and that is causing Binding errors.

EDIT: does the following do what you are looking for?

```
myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv", {
    layout: $(go.TreeLayout, { isInitial: false, isOngoing: false })
   });

myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $(go.Node, "Auto",
    new go.Binding("location", "loc").makeTwoWay(),
    $(go.Shape, { fill: "white"}),
    $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 8 }, new go.Binding("text", "key"))
  );

myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel([
  { key: "Alpha", loc: new go.Point(30, 50) },
  { key: "Beta", loc: new go.Point(80, 10) },
  { key: "Gamma", loc: new go.Point(130, 70) },
  { key: "Delta", loc: new go.Point(110, 100) }
], [
  { from: "Alpha", to: "Beta" }, { from: "Alpha", to: "Gamma" }, { from: "Beta", to: "Beta" }, { from: "Gamma", to: "Delta" }, { from: "Delta", to: "Alpha" } ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no error or warning when using GOJS debug version. As you said now the Diagram.layout doesn't automatically move the nodes. 
I want the diagram with Treelayout and able to position the nodes wherever I want. I am giving the data.loc as Point values. But still not positioning based on the location set.